# Implementing protection for source images

Tags: javascript, html

While browsing I came across this [link](http://cars-database.com/data_images/models/aston-martin-db9/aston-martin-db9-03.jpg)

As you can see image is protected, if you browse [cars-database.com](http://cars-database.com/) you take source image and you will get the same message.

This is first time I see this and I wonder how this has been implemented? Does anybody know?

Screenshot of protected source image:

[image]

Comment: It's not protected. Just open the image in a new tab. You will see the normal image without the overlapping message.

Comment: @KeesSonnema I am using Chrome and I see protection, if I download it image is fine. I will add screenshot.

Comment: Probably some simple checking of the REFERER header.

Comment: I use chrome too. You can just open that image in a new tab. (right click > open in new tab) and you have the image you wanted.

Comment: @deceze: +1 yes they are. You can simply try out with devtools.

Comment: See my screenshot, when I open the image in a new tab. http://i.imgur.com/9TZGce4.jpg

Comment: @KeesSonnema What I do usually i Right Click > Copy Image URL that is when I get this. Also it is interesting when using google images and you try to view source you will get same message.

Comment: Yes copying the image url and pasting it right after that won't work, but opening the image in a new tab does.

Comment: its possible they are using some fancy url rewrite on the server that swaps the original image for a pre-protected version when trying to access the file directly.

Comment: This is hotlink protection, not general protection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example on how to implement something similar in `nginx`:

```
location ~ \.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ {
     valid_referers none blocked mysite.com *.mysite.com;
     if ($invalid_referer) {
        rewrite ^ http://mysite.com/lowres$request_uri permanent;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

They likely simply have two versions of the image stored on the server, the "real" one and one with the extra message added via a Photoshop template or something. They then employ a check for the [Referer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referer) header like:

```
if request for image and referer is not cars-database.com/*
    then serve "watermarks/$requestedImage$"
```

This can be implemented trivially with an Apache mod_rewrite rule, any other web server's rule system or any server-side programming language like PHP, Python or whatnot.